# how to use .htaccess file to remove page detail

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my .htaaccess code.

```
#Remove .php extension
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I need clean url for my website. i have already remove .php extension. how to show just page name like `www.xyz.com/courses` not like  `www.xyz.com/page?page-name=Courses`?

```
<a href="www.xyz.com/page?page-name=Courses"> My Website </a>
```

I want to show like `www.xyz.com/Courses`

Comment: I would recommend looking into the [front controller pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) together with some [router](https://packagist.org/?query=router). Then you just set up all URL's in your code directly. This is also how the majority of semi modern to modern frameworks/applications does it. (it will also work "out of the box" with PHP's dev server (which uses the front controller pattern as default)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rules :

```
 #Remove .php extension
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
#######Clean URLs########
#Redirect /page.php?page-name=Courses to /Courses
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /page\.php\?page-name=([^\s]+)\s [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /%1? [L,R]
#Internally map new URL to the original one
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?page-name=$1 [L]
```

Make sure to change `page.php` to your original page name in the condition pattern and in the rewrite destination .